# Put ProgressBar in CENTER of the screen programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I'm making a class which is extending `LinearLayout`. In that I'm trying to make layout programmatically. Here is what I have done so far:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parentParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    this.setLayoutParams(parentParam);
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    WebView webView = new WebView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams webViewParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    webView.setLayoutParams(webViewParam);
    this.addView(webView);

    pb = new ProgressBar(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams pbParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pbParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    pb.setLayoutParams(pbParam);
    webView.addView(pb);
```

My all things are working fine, `WebView` and `ProgressBar` are visible and doing there respective task, but I'm trying to put `ProgressBar` in the `CENTER` of the screen.

What am I missing here. Any kind of input will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The output right now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What you get in output, post here.

Comment: why do you add pb to webview? You should add pb to this.addView

Comment: @PratikButani Added image

Comment: @blackbelt Because I have to load some content in webview, so I need to show progress bar there.

Comment: I think it is problem of RelativeLayout. You have to set `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` Programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did to bring `ProgressBar` in the center. I have used `ScrollView` for my purpose. Here is the code which I have used:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parentParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    this.setLayoutParams(parentParam);
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    scrollView = new ScrollView(context);
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL));
    scrollView.setFillViewport(true);

    scrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    pb = new ProgressBar(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams pbParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pb.setLayoutParams(pbParam);

    RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    rel.addView(pb, relParam);

    scrollView.addView(rel);

    webView = new WebView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams webViewParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    webViewParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
            | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    webView.setLayoutParams(webViewParam);

    this.addView(scrollView);

    this.addView(webView);
```

Hope, this will help others, who are trying the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
// try this way
1. Custom Linear Layout
public class MyCustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private  WebView webView;
    public MyCustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context mContext) {
        frameLayout = new FrameLayout(mContext);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        webView = new WebView(mContext);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                if (newProgress >= 1) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (newProgress == 100) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        frameLayout.addView(webView);
        pb = new ProgressBar(mContext);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams parms = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        frameLayout.addView(pb,parms);
        addView(frameLayout);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
    lp.weight = 1.0f;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    ProgressBar pDialog = new ProgressBar(currentActivity);
    pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(currentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressload));

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(currentActivity);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.addView(pDialog, lp);
```